# ClojureScript - Ajax - Retrieving json

Tags: json, ajax, clojurescript

I have my dependencies

```
(ns test.core
    (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
              [ajax.core :refer [GET]]))
```

I then have my handler that handles the responses to my ajax call

```
(defn handle-response [response]
    (println (type response))
    (println film))
```

THe data from my call is JSON, in the browser it looks like this:

```
{"id":3,"name":"Sicario","star":"Emily Blunt","rating":5}
```

When I run the above Clojure, I see this:

```
cljs.core/PersistentArrayMap core.cljs:192:23
{id 3, name Sicario, star Emily Blunt, rating 5}
```

Is their a way for me to go from the PersistArrayMap, and destructure it into `id`, `name`, `star` and `rating`?

I tried

```
(let [film (js->clj (.parse js/JSON response) :keywordize-keys true)]
   ...)
```

Hoping I would get a map named film, but no avail!

I think maybe I could use `(get-in)`, but can't get the syntax right for this either.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it,

I was missing `:response-format :json` and `:keywords? true` from my GET call

Now, it looks like this:

```
(GET (str "https://localhost:5001/api/films/" film-name)
         {:response-format :json
          :keywords? true
```

And it all works.